# Increment Tabs using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I an using Tabs in foreach, This is my code:

```
foreach ($pdts as $pdt=>$r){

    echo'<tr>';
        echo'
        <td><div style="width: 10px;"><span id="plus-'.$pdt.'"> + </span><br/>


            </div></td>
        <td><div style="width:200px; text-align:center">'.$r['Product_Number'].'</div></td>
        <td><div  style="width:200px; text-align:center">'.$r['Barcode'].'</div></td>
        <td><div  style="width:150px; text-align:center">'.$r['Product_Name'].'</div></td>
        <td><div  style="width:200px; text-align:center">'.$r['Supplier_Number'].'</div></td>
        <td><div  style="width:200px; text-align:center">'.$r['Stock_Number'].'</div></td>';
        $sql_stk="SELECT Stock_Name FROM stock where Stock_Number='".$r['Stock_Number']."'";
        $stks = db_query($database_name, $sql_stk);
        //var_dump($stks );
            foreach ($stks as $stk=>$s){
                echo'   <td style="text-align:center; width:120px; ">'.$s['Stock_Name'].'</td>';
            }
        echo'<td style="text-align:center; width:120px; ">'.$r['Purchasing_Price'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align:center; width:120px; ">'.$r['Selling_Price'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align:center; width:120px; ">'.$r['Quantity'].'</td>';
         echo'</tr>
         <tr><td colspan="10"><div id="detail-'.$pdt.'" >
         <div id="tabs-'.$pdt.'">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Sales Detail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Purchases Detail</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. </p>
              </div>
              <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus,</p>
              </div>
        </div>

    </div>';

}
```

So for each product, I have a specific tabs with information that refers to the product.

```js
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
```

How can I call every tabs for each product using Jquery?
Thank's for your help

Comment: Could you please post rendered `html`?

Comment: <div id="tabs-0">
     <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Sales Detail</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Purchases Detail</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div id="tabs-1"><p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. </p>
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus,</p>
     </div>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $('[id^="detail-"]').hide();
   
    $('[id^="plus-"]').click(function() {
     alert('ALLAH');
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
      
        var idx=id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("-"));
         
      $("#detail"+idx).toggle(500); 
      $( "#tab"+idx ).tabs();      
    });
   });

   </script>
```

and :

```
<div id="tab-'.$pdt.'">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Sales Detail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Purchases Detail</a></li>
              </ul>
```